# Ubuntu doesn't recognize I upgraded to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, software-installation

I Upgraded my 20.04 Ubuntu to 22.04, the installation process went well, but after the restart - my computer doesn't recognize the upgrade and it tells me I'm still running on 20.04
though I have many errors mostly when I write Python code and using Django. seems like the packages are broken.
I think the best way would be to reinstall Ubuntu, the thing is I don't see any other version available for download other than 22.04 or 22.10.

Comment: https://releases.ubuntu.com/

Comment: This link to the download is direct. https://releases.ubuntu.com/focal/